# In WooCommerce is there a shortcode for Thankyou page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

How to get Thankyou page shortcode?

I want make custom page using Thankyou page shortcode.

I have made custom cart page using cart shortcode: [woocommerce_cart]

Now I need woocommerce Thankyou page shortcode.

Comment: Sorry but there is no Thankyou page shortcode… Thankyou page is an endpoint linked to checkout page, **so it uses checkout page**… Same thing for "Order pay" page.